# Changing the openGL coordinate system

Tags: opengl, shapes

Right now, my openGL window scales from -1 to 1 on both the X and Y axis. How would I change this, to say, -2 and 2?

Answer (score 1):

Add transformation for halving every coordinate: `glScalef(0.5,0.5,0.5);`. Note however, you won't get far without understanding OpenGL matrices, various transformations you can add and working with the stacks. See, for example, OpenGL FAQs regarding [transformations](http://www.opengl.org/resources/faq/technical/transformations.htm) and in more detail, the [specification](http://www.opengl.org/documentation/specs/).

Answer (score 1):

If working as 2D (say ortho), change it to the:

```
 gluOrtho2D(-2,2,-2,2)
```

Comment: This definitely the way to go here.  Using glScalef would cause unnecessary headaches especially if you started changing which matrix model you using.